# Using htaccess to forward /tags/ to /blog/tags/

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a client where the previous designer moved the WP blog to the /blog/ subdirectory. However, instead of creating an htaccess rule that moved all the tags and categories to redirect to /blog/tags/ and /blog/categories/, they did everything manually in the WP Redirection plugin.

We think this is slowing the site down and want to see if we can reduce the lengthy list of tag and category redirects. What we want to do is have all tags redirected to blog/tags/ Example: /tags/real-estate should redirect to /blog/tags/real-estate

I don't have the programing knowledge to figure out the rules myself. I'm usually just decent at finding snippets and copying and pasting them.

Thanks, in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(tags.*)$ /blog/$1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm going to remove a handful of software redirects at a time and test them to ensure that this really is what we're looking for. Thank you so much!